# Openssl ГОСТ на PHP

Tags: php, debian, openssl, гост

Как подружить PHP и ГОСТ?

В самом *Openssl* я его настроил, и все работает, но *PHP* его не видит.

Нагуглил, что надо перед строчкой

```
SSL_library_init();
```

поставить

```
OPENSSL_config(NULL);
```

и все заработает. Но проблема в том, что я понятия не имею, где этот самый `SSL_library_init();`. файлы, о которых шла речь, либо у меня отсутствуют (`openssl.c`), либо в них не тот `SSL_library_init()`, что нужен.

Сервер на *Debian 7*.

Comment: *у меня отсутствуют (openssl.c)* — скорее всего, речь о файле, входящем в исходники php. как пересобрать пакет, наложив на исходники патч, описано, например, [здесь](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial) или [здесь](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb). ну, помимо [официальной документации](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.ru.html), которая переведена на русский, но несколько многословна.

Comment: Да, это я затупил. Речь действительно идет о пересборки PHP.